# IF returns FALSE when it sould return TRUE

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements

I tried to do something like this

```
sub test()
a=inputbox("value1:")
b=inputbox("value2:")
c=inputbox("value3:")

  if a<b and a>c then 

    msgbox(a)

    else
      msgbox(b)
      msgbox(c)
   end if

end sub
```

when I enter values such as 5 for a, 10 for b and 2 for c, condition should return TRUE and then message box with a is shown, but it returns FALSE and displays message boxes with b and c. I think the solution is pretty simple but I can't figure it out.

thanks a lot

Comment: Use a=CLng(inputbox("value1:")), and the likes, to have strings converted into longs (or use CDbl() if you expect not integer values)

Comment: What are the *types* of the variables? You should get in the habit of declaring them with `Dim`. Use `Option Explicit` to force yourself to do so. If you had declared them to be a numerical type, this wouldn't have been an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because VBA is treating your input as strings. Just add a CInt() or a CLng() to the variables to excel know that they are numeric.

```
Sub test()

a = CInt(InputBox("value1:"))
b = CInt(InputBox("value2:"))
c = CInt(InputBox("value3:"))

  If a < b And a > c Then
    MsgBox (a)

    Else
      MsgBox (b)
      MsgBox (c)
   End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Your InputBoxes are returning strings that look like numbers and `"5"` is not less than `"10"`. Do one of the following:

- `Dim a as long, b as long, c as long`
- Use [Application.InputBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox) with Type:=1 argument.
- Convert the strings to real numbers like `a=clng(inputbox("value1:"))` or `if int(a)<int(b) and int(a)>int(c) then`.

Answer (score 1):

The other two answers are excellent and I would **ultimately go with Jeeped's explicit variable declaration method** (`Dim a as long, b as long, c as long`).

While I would never suggest *not declaring your variables* - which you found out the hard way why it's always good practice to do so - you could also simply multiply your inputbox by 1.

Here's just another trick to force a string to a numerical value using the power of multiplication *(this is a similar trick used in worksheet formulas that use the double negative `--()` to convert a value into a number)*.

```
a = InputBox("value1:") * 1
b = InputBox("value2:") * 1
c = InputBox("value3:") * 1

If a < b And a > c Then

    MsgBox (a)

Else

    MsgBox (b)
    MsgBox (c)

End If
```